# Pull Bitcoin node data from external public nodes using JSON-RPC

Tags: json-rpc, full-node

I read couple of blogs and responses on hosting server to expose data using JSON-RPC but wanted to confirm if there is a way to query node data that I am not hosting (not connecting via P1P) using JSON-RPC protocol (or any other protocol that allows querying data and not pull everything)

Note: I am talking about mainnet and not testnet

Comment: The port has to be bound explicitly to the Internet. Why do you want this? What's the problem you need to resolve?

Comment: I want to query Bitcoin node for some specific data like transaction. I do not want to host my own BTC node

Answer (score -1):

> OP posted:
>
> > I read couple of blogs and responses on hosting server to expose data using JSON-RPC but wanted to confirm if there is a way to query node data that I am not hosting (not connecting via P1P) using JSON-RPC protocol (or any other protocol that allows querying data and not pull everything)
> >
> > Note: I am talking about mainnet and not testnet
>
> OP clarified in a comment:
>
> > I want to query Bitcoin node for some specific data like transaction. I do not want to host my own BTC node

Yeah, you can query node data that you are not hosting using JSON-RPC.

However, there are many other options you can use:

1. Use a node's REST API, Bitcoin Core REST API.
2. Use a REST API provided by some third party, like for instance any famous Bitcoin data analytics platform, or any famous blocks chain explorer.
3. Contribute a full node to the network and query it privately.

The third option is actually the easiest to get, [by largely far] the most secure, the most readily available, the least vendor lock in, the cheapest to maintain, and the most beneficial to the Bitcoin ecosystem.

Comment: If you don't have access to a node's RPC interface, you won't have access to its REST interface either (assuming you're talking about Bitcoin Core).